# Jdeveloper hanging often while working on SOA Suite 12c

Tags: weblogic, soa, jdeveloper

I am trying to create a project in the SOA suite in Jdeveloper 12c. When I am creating Decision Rule table in the Business Rule component, the editor is hanging a lot.

Whenever I start my Integrated Weblogic server, I am getting Java SE error and after several attempts I am able to do that.

Please provide some suggestions to overcome above issues

Answer (score 0):

How much memory does your machine has?
Did you try allocating more memory to the embedded WebLogic Server?

Comment: I have 8GB RAm and 465 GB C drive with a free space of 347 GB. Can you please share how to allocate more space to integrated server

Comment: Locate the defaultdomain directory in your JDeveloper user system12.x.x.x directory - in the bin directory under it there are the weblogic config files that you can modify. for example: http://jianmingli.com/wp/?p=3761